# Time dependent operators in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, fourier-transform, commutator, time-evolution

In Quantum field theory, how does one define time-dependent operators? For example, let me generalize the operator fermion $\psi$:

$\psi(x) = \int \frac{d^3p}{2 (\pi)^3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2E_p}} \sum_s \left (a_{\bf{p}}^s u^s(p)e^{-ipx} + b_{\bf{p}}^s v^s(p)e^{ipx} \right ) ...............(1) $

to

$\psi(x) = \int \frac{d^3p}{2 (\pi)^3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2E_p}} \sum_s \left (c_1(t)a_{\bf{p}}^s u^s(p)e^{-ipx} + c_2(t) b_{\bf{p}}^s v^s(p)e^{ipx} \right ) .............. (2)$

I've introduced $c_1(t)$ and $c_2(t)$, in order to incorporate the fact that the number of particles or anti-particles created (or annihilated) may vary with time.
The particle anti-particle creation and annihilation operators $a_{\bf{p}}$ and $b_{\bf{p}}$ satisfy the usual anti-commutation relation for fermions.

The problem in Eq. (2) that I see is with the anti-commutator $\{\psi_a(\bf{x}),\psi_b^{\dagger}(\bf{y})\}$ , does not seem to satisfy the anti-commutation relation $\{\psi_a(\bf{x}),\psi_b^{\dagger}(\bf{y})\} = \delta^3(\bf{x-y})\delta_{ab}$, due to the additional factors $c_1(t)$ and $c_2(t)$ coming into picture.

Is there any known way of extending the QFT operators to a time varying system?

Comment: Normally the time dependence comes in because you are working in the "Interaction Picture" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaction_picture).

Comment: The field operator is already time dependent because $x$ represents $\mathbf{x}$ and $t$. In the exponent $\exp(-ixp)=\exp(-i\omega t + i \mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x})$.

Comment: true, but $\exp(-ixp)$ would not lead to a time dependent system (e.g. time dependent Lagrangian).

Comment: Isn't everyone who writes $S = \int L \, dt$ working with a time dependent Lagrangian?

Comment: Let us take the terms one by one: $a_p$ is not time dependent. $p$, $E$ are not time dependent. so $a_pe^{-ipx}$ is not time dependent. The only time dependence comes from $e^{-i\omega t}$. This factor would cancel away in terms like $\psi^{\dagger}\psi$. If $L$ is indeed time dependent, please let me know where it comes from?

Comment: From the fact that $e^{i\omega t}$ and $e^{-i\omega t}$ are both there?